# I want to display no scrollbar in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to display the calendar with NO scrollbar on the right. I tried setting contentHeight but it is not working as intended.  There is no scrollbar and the calendar is all displayed, but it streches the rows so that they are all the same height as the row with the most events.

Example, row 3 of the month has 10 events, so the row will strech to display all 10 events, however ALL other rows will have the same height even empty rows.

I tried with this value. contentHeight: 2800

The EventLimit is set to False.  As I want every events to be displayed.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the `height` to `auto`? Check to [official doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/).

I hope it helps. ;)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay to answer :-S.  I'm not on this project anymore so I cannot check back but the solution was something like this.  Thanks :-)